# Trouble with Heroku Deployment and Interpreting Heroku Log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4.1

**This is my last resort to figure this out.** I've searched through stackoverflow and googled various topics, but it seems to come down to how to interpret/analyze my own Heroku log. There's so much going on that I'm not sure where to look first. I see things like `eager_load` and direction to files `app/config/environment:rb:5` and there also seems to be issues with my Unicorn configurations and relationship associations. I've gone through my files and haven't been able to locate what my logs are referring to, up until now it's been really easy to interpret errors.

**A little background:** I had originally built my rails app with the default Sqlite3 settings and I have attempted to switch it to Postgres. So maybe there's some conflicts with that going on as well. I want to be able to read my Heroku Logs in the future on my own and know exactly where to look. So if someone could provide a good tutorial about reading Heroku Logs that would be great as well.

**Here's where I've looked so far:**
I've looked on devcenter on heroku's website, but I'm not making the connection from their instructions, to the issue in my code. I'm just a that stuck point, but have been trying to figure it out for days! I'm worried that I'm just missing something basic, which is why I haven't been able to figure this out yet.

I've also looked at association_basics.html on ruby on rails guides because I've been having some syntax issues.

I've used `foreman start` to see if my Procfile is working and have gotten another huge list. I've also used `heroku ps`, which gives me `web.1 crashed`

**Here's the Heroku Log that's also connected to my app's github page:**
https://github.com/jsmit032/seasons-app/issues/29

If any other information is required, please let me know and I'll edit my questions so hopefully this can help others as well.

Comment: It sounds like everything's on fire.  You mention a dozen issues.  Please pick one to start with.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is there any information you can tell me about how heroku logs groups errors. From the look of things there are multiple lines of the same error. Should I just take the first line and research that specific one. I did read the how to ask a good question. This was my first shot at it.

Comment: The log output is that same as would you see locally - it's just prefixed with timestamp and source weg web[1] etc. Chances are if you started your application locally in production mode you'd see the same errors.

Comment: Great thanks! It's actually working locally. Maybe I just didn't notice those errors too. I'll take a look at that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the whole app to deploy! Turns out it was a pre-complied issue.

So I went through the guide on Heroku for pre-compiling assets in Rails 4: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

I also went through the heroku guide for prepping your rails 4 app:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#migrate-your-database

Also went through the heroku guide for **SQLite on Heroku** and the **Deploying Rails Applications with Unicorn** guide.

Looking through the console errors on the actual site was a huge help. It's how we figured out that the assets pipeline might not be working.

Answer (score 0):

```
2014-11-21T19:27:58.271705+00:00 app[web.1]: has_many :user, through :user_to_destinations
```

doesn't look right - it should be

```
has_many :user, through: :user_to_destinations
```

at /app/app/models/destination.rb:3

Comment: typically you want to scan the logs for filenames that look familiar - ie your code, usually in the /app folder - these can show you where the problems are in your code.

Comment: That fixed one thing! I am now just getting a blank page! I'm getting a better idea of how to read the logs. *just saw new comment above!*